# SQL: Count items by day (where day must be converted)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you in advance for reading my question. I have data like this:

```
| Date_Time               | City | Vehicle_ID |
'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'   'A'       1159
'2017-01-01 13:12:00.000'   'A'       1159
'2017-01-02 01:00:34.000'   'B'       1323
'2017-01-02 02:00:25.000'   'A'       1159
```

I would like to calculate a new column 'Day_Number' which represents the interval of days from min(Date_Time) + 1, and then count the unique(Vehicle_IDs) by 'City' and by 'Day_Number'.

Example:

```
| City | Day | count_unique_vehicles |
  'A'     1             2
  'A'     2             1
  'B'     2             1
```

I have written some terrible sql like

```
 select date_time, city, count(distinct Vehicle_ID) as unique_vehicle
 from X
 where date_time >= '2017-12-01 00:00:00.000'
 group by DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,'2017-12-01', date_time), date_time), Division
```

which doesn't work. What should my query look like?

Comment: I believe it is mysql. "Micrsoft SQL Server Enterprise, version 11" is listed in the properties of the instance.

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
A.CITY, DATEDIFF(DAY, B.DAY_0, A.DATE_TIME) AS DAY, COUNT(DISTINCT A.VEHICLE_ID) AS UNIQUE_VEHICLE
FROM
YOUR_TABLE A, (SELECT MIN(DATE_TIME) AS DAY_0 FROM YOUR_TABLE) B
GROUP BY A.CITY, DATEDIFF(DAY, B.DAY_0, A.DATE_TIME)
ORDER BY A.CITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with window functions:

```
select t.city,
       datediff(day, min(min(t.date_time)) over (), cast(t.date_time as date)) as days,
       count(distinct t.vehicle_id) as num_uniques
from t
group by t.city, cast(t.date_time as date)
order by t.city, days;
```

Note:  This will return `0` for the value on the minimum day.  That makes sense to me.  However, you can just add 1 if you want `1` instead.

Comment: When I run the above statement, I receive the error:

't.date_time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thank you for your answer!